# Как нормально вытащить значения из БД

Tags: sql, mysql

MySQL

Есть таблица `center`, в ней два столбца `date` и  `assesstament`.
В столбике date есть все полугодие тоесть 230 дней записанных вот так `15/03/12`. И как мне вытащить пять значений, начиная с даты пять дней назад.

То есть если сейчас `04/01/12`, мне надо вытащить с `31/12/11` до сегодня(`04/01/12`)

---

Не пашит, массив пустой

```
  $result = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT assessment FROM `31.Informatics` WHERE `date` = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY"));

 foreach ($result as $data)
  {
   echo $data['assessment'];
  }

    function fetch($request) 
  {
   $resData = array();    
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($request)) 
      {
        $resData[] = $row;
          }
   return $resData;
     }
```

Comment: Какая СУБД - Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL?

Comment: CУБД MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM center
WHERE `date` = CURRDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

`CURRDATE()` - в MySQL это текущая дата. Можно заменить на свою константу.

P.S.: Правило хорошего тона: имена таблиц, столбцов, процедур (вообще любые пользовательские сущности) именовать так, чтобы они не совпадали с стандартными определениями (типы, операторы, встроенные функции)...

Comment: она возвращает пустой массив

Comment: Какой тип у поля `date`?